Fluent API Marking Abstract Nullable Field as Required
I'm working on implementing a library to enforce the Auditable Entity design pattern, aiming for easy implementation across projects for both Entities and their configuration. Here's my current setup:
public interface IAuditable<T, TId>
{
    DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    TId CreatedById { get; set; }
    T CreatedBy { get; set; }
    TId? UpdatedById { get; set; }
    T? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AuditableEntity<T, TId> : IAuditable<T, TId>
{
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public TId CreatedById { get; set; }
    public T CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public TId? UpdatedById { get; set; }
    public T? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AuditableEntityTypeConfiguration<T, TId, Th> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Th>
    where Th : AuditableEntity<T, TId> 
    where T : class
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Th> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(e => e.UpdatedOn);
    
        builder.HasOne(x => x.CreatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.CreatedById)
        .IsRequired();
    
        builder.HasOne(x => x.UpdatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.UpdatedById);
    }
}

public class Paper : AuditableEntity<User, Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...

}

However, when I attempt to make a migration, it always returns changes making the previously nullable property UpdatedById to now be required.
I've tried adding this to my OnModelCreating in addition to implementing the abstract class as AuditableEntity<User, Guid?> in my DbContext:
modelBuilder.Entity<Paper>().Property(p => p.UpdatedById).IsRequired(false); 
modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>().Property(p => p.UpdatedById).IsRequired(false);

Upon running the migration, I am left with:
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type '{MyDbContext}'. The exception 'The property 'Paper.UpdatedById' cannot be marked as nullable/optional because the type of the property is 'Guid' which is not a nullable type. Any property can be marked as non-nullable/required, but only properties of nullable types can be marked as nullable/optional.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see here.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?
EDIT:
I have found a work around specific for value types being passed as nullable. I had to update my IAuditable interface to be like so:
public interface IAudtiable<T, TId> where TId : struct
{
...
Nullable<TId> UpdatedById {get; set;}
...
}

However, this now disallows the use of strings as ids and overall puts pressure on the user's implementation to have the mutating entities Id type be a value type, which seems to be outside of the scope of this library in my opinion.

The problem is in the type you pass as a generic argument. Since Guid is a value type, the T? doesn't actually work in the way you expect.
Rules for nullable types in generics are explained in the docs:


If the type argument for T is a reference type, T? references the corresponding nullable reference type. For example, if T is a
string, then T? is a string?.
If the type argument for T is a value type, T? references the same value type, T. For example, if T is an int, the T? is
also an int.
If the type argument for T is a nullable reference type, T? references that same nullable reference type. For example, if T is a
string?, then T? is also a string?.
If the type argument for T is a nullable value type, T? references that same nullable value type. For example, if T is a
int?, then T? is also a int?.


I haven't tested it, but changing Guid to Guid? while keeping the IsRequired() method on CreatedById property relationship might solve your problem.
Update
In case you want to keep the CreatedById non-null, you can change your interface to explicitly take the nullable value type, then add another interface implementation with two generic types for reference types only:
public interface IAuditable<T, TId, TNullableId>
{
    DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    TId CreatedById { get; set; }
    T CreatedBy { get; set; }
    TNullableId? UpdatedById { get; set; }
    T? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AuditableEntity<T, TId, TNullableId> : IAuditable<T, TId, TNullableId>
{
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public TId CreatedById { get; set; }
    public T CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public TNullableId? UpdatedById { get; set; }
    public T? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AuditableEntity<T, TId> : AuditableEntity<T, TId, TId>
    where TId : class
{
}

And then to use it with value types:
public class Paper : AuditableEntity<User, Guid, Guid?>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...

}

And to use it with reference types:
public class Paper : AuditableEntity<User, string>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    ...

}


You are correct that the reason was GUID's being a reference type. However, passing in Guid? will make it seem as though the CreatedId is nullable even though the required configuration makes it not. To me, that would be confusing to explain to any developer "If you want your mutating entity to have a nullable value type updatedById, you must also make the createdById nullable"

@JustinFay The problem you are trying to solve is that you have two different types: Guid and Guid? (a.k.a. Nullable<Guid>), but you want to pass only one type argument. To make this possible you need your interface to have three type arguments, for example: IAuditable<T, TId, TNullableId>, and then add a generic overload for reference types": IAuditable<T, TId> : IAuditable<T, TId, TId> where TId : class.

I have updated the answer with suitable examples.

Thank you very much! This was the approach I went with but implemented slightly differently!
